# Confirmation message in webgrid

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, webgrid

I am using Webgrid in MVC.And I was added in default column in the webgrid  with link  button(anchor tag). Now I want  when the button click shown a confirmation message . But I  tried in below code

```
gridColumns.Add(grid.Column(
            format: 
    @<text>
    @if (item.complianceStatusId == (int)SchoolBreifcase.Models.Status.Tobeverified)
    {    
        @Html.ActionLink("Complete", "CompleteComplianceTask", new { complianceId = item.ComplianceId, statusId = item.complianceStatusId },
         new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to complete  this compliance ?');" }, new { @class = "gridButton" }) 
    }
    </text>
```

Its showing error like : **The best overloaded method match for `'System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid.Column(string, string, System.Func<dynamic,object>, string, bool)'` has some invalid arguments**

**I removed the css class or confirmation ,then Its working fine** .But I want  to confirmation message ,and  assign CSS class in the same field . How to do i solve this ??

I think  i want  for set css style like as webgrid,a {Styles } then we can remove the @class field in   the anchor tag . But I try this .the css style not assigned in gridview button .

**Edit:**
Now i got the answer .I just changed for like below code

```
@Html.ActionLink("Complete", "CompleteComplianceTask", new { complianceId = item.ComplianceId, statusId = item.complianceStatusId },
             **new { @class = "gridButton", onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to complete  this task ?');"** })
```

I am assigned the css class and confirmation messge in same object ,then it working perfect .